# The meaning of an intertwiner?

Tags: tensor-products, rt.representation-theory

I think that a reformulation of my question is necessary:
An intertwiner $\iota:\; V_{j_{1}}\bigotimes V_{j_{2}}\rightarrow V_{j_{3}}$ is defined as:

$\forall g\in SU(2),\;\forall u_{i},v_{i},w_{i},...\in V_{j_{i}}:\;\iota((\rho_{j_{1}}\bigotimes\rho_{j_{2}})(g)\;[v_{1}\bigotimes v_{2}])=\rho_{j_{3}}(g)[\iota(v_{1}\bigotimes v_{2})]$

where $\rho_{j_{i}}$ is the representation map corresponding to the irrep of spin $j_i$ of $SU(2)$, and $V_{j_i}$ are the invariant spaces upon which acts the $\rho_{j_{i}}(g)$ for $g\in SU(2)$

I know that the Shur's lemma is: if

$\iota:\; V_{j}\rightarrow V_{k}$

is an interwtwiner, then is it either a scalar (if $j=k$) or zero ($j\not= k$)

Now, what I want to know, is if $V_{j_{1}}\bigotimes V_{j_{2}} = \dots\oplus V_{j_{2}} \oplus \dots$ take an example  $V_{j_{1}}\bigotimes V_{j_{2}} = V_{j_{4}} \oplus V_{j_{2}} \oplus V_{j_{5}}$ I can write:

$\forall g\in SU(2),\;\forall u_{i},v_{i},w_{i},...\in V_{j_{i}}:\;\iota((\rho_{j_{4}}\oplus\rho_{j_{3}}\oplus\rho_{j_{5}})(g)\;[v_{1}\bigotimes v_{2}])=\rho_{j_{3}}(g)[\iota(v_{1}\bigotimes v_{2})]$

in this case how to prove that $\iota$ is a scalar? (by Shur's lemma)

Comment: I don't understand.  If I am reading your question correctly, you are asking how to prove that an ${\rm SU}(2)$-equivariant map `$W_1\otimes W_2 \to W_3$` is a scalar, where the `$W_i$` are irreps.  But it will not be: indeed, unless `$W_1$` is the trivial irrep, then `$W_1\otimes W_2$` is not an irrep, and so certainly not isomorphic to `$W_3$`, and so a map between them cannot be a multiple of the identity, because there is no identity between them.

Comment: What if $W_1\bigotimes W_2$ decomposes to a sum that contains $W_3$ ?

Comment: So what Baez means in gr-qc/9905087 in pp 18?
>"each basis of intertwiners $\iota:\; j_1 \bigotimes j_2 \rightarrow j_3$ contains at most one element."

Comment: Why do you use $\bigotimes$ instead of just $\otimes$?

Comment: Sorry I thought that the bug is general, in my browser (chrome) $\otimes$ does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

I presume by $V_j$ you mean the $j$-dimensional (or maybe $(j+1)$-dimensional)
representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. I wouldn't write something like
$j_i\otimes j_2\to j_3$ since that notation confuses the represntation
$V_j$ with the label $j$. I would write $\iota:V_{j_i}\otimes V_{j_2}\to V_{j_3}$.
This notation is honest in the sense that it exhibits the spaces between
which $\iota$ is a map.

To simplify notation further I would write $\iota : W_1\otimes W_2\to W_3$
and assume that the $W_i$ are repsentations of any group $G$. Then $\iota$
is an intertwiner (or module homomorphism) if
$$\iota(g v_1\otimes g v_2)=g \iota(v_1\otimes v_2)$$
for any $g\in G$ and $v_i\in V_i$. The intertwiners form a vector space
$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\otimes V_2,V_3)$.

In your example, take $V_i$ to be the $(j_i+1)$-dimensional irreducible
representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ then $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\otimes V_2,V_3)$
is nonzero if and only if $j_3$ has the same parity as $j_1+j_2$ and
$ | j_1-j_2 |< j_3\le j_1+j_2 $. In this case
$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\otimes V_2,V_3)$ is one-dimensional, but note
that this is a very special property of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: it's precisely what bothers me: 
* why `$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\bigotimes V_2,V_3)$` is nonzero only if `$j_3$`has same parity as `$j_1+j_2$` and... 
* why `$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\bigotimes V_2,V_3)$` is one dimensional if the previous condition is fullfiled 

Comment: This is a special fact about $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. One looks at
the action of diagonal matrices $\mathrm{diag}(u,1/u)$
on the representation. An irreducible representaion breaks up
into "weight spaces" where this matrix multiplies the vector
by $u^j$. The representation $V_j$ splits into one-dimensional
weight spaces of weights $-j$, $-(j-2)$, $-(j-4),\dots,j$.
To count the number of irreps of a given type in a finite-dimensional
representation one does a census of the weight spaces.
If you do that for $V_i\otimes V_j$ you find that the stated
irreps turn up just once each.

Comment: I know that the a given irrep space shows up just one time in the tensorial sum decomposition of a tensorial product, my question is perhaps silly but why if I have `$\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1\bigotimes V_2,V_3) \equiv \mathrm{Hom}_G(...\oplus V_3 \oplus ...,V_3)$` then `$\mathrm{Hom}_G$` is 1-dimensional, and zero otherwise.

Comment: A question that may shed light on my confusion: If I have two irreps `$\rho_{j_1}$` and `$\rho_{j_2}$` of SU(2), does the condition `$\iota \circ \rho_{j_1} = \rho_{j_2} \circ \iota$` implies that $\iota$ is identically zero?

Comment: I'm not sure what your $\rho$s are, but by Schur's lemma
if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional complex irreducible
representations of a group $G$ then either $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W)$
is one-dimensional or zero-dimensional according to whether or
not $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic. Also can I recommend
Fulton and Harris's book *Representation Theory* as an excellent
introduction to the representation theory of classical Lie groups.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an intertwiner between a representation $V$ to a representation $W$ of a group $G$, say, is a *$G$-equivariant* linear map from $V$ to $W$.

In your example, assuming that $j_3 \in \lbrace |j_1-j_2|,|j_1-j_2|+1,\dots,j_1+j_2\rbrace$, there is precisely one $V_{j_3}$ factor in the decomposition of $V_{j_1} \otimes V_{j_2}$ into irreducibles:
$$ V_{j_1} \otimes V_{j_2} \cong  V_{|j_1-j_2|} \oplus V_{|j_1-j_2|+1} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{j_1+j_2}.$$
(This is the Clebsch-Gordan series.)

The map $\iota$ is then simply the projection onto $V_{j_3}$ along its complement.

Comment: Is it the fact that `$\iota$` is an intertwinet that renders it the projection onto `$V_{j_3}$`?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that there is no nonzero $G$-equivariant linear map from $V_j$ to $V_k$ unless $j=k$.

Comment: Above I should have simply put $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)$.


Comment: Can you give a simple proof of that, or at least a justification?

Comment: @Pedro: $V_j$ and $V_k$ are irreducible.  Try to work out what the kernel and cokernel of such an equivariant map could be.

Comment: Ok sorry silly question: it's the shur's lemma